# Fragment gets created after the activity has stopped

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a problem with the lifecycle in my app. There's some code which commits a fragment to the fragment manager:

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mModuleFragment)
            .commit();
```

There are certain actions you can do in the app that will run the above code (i.e. commit the fragment), and if followed by using the home button, will lead to a crash. I've looked through the stack trace and here's what I think is happening:

1) Fragment replace gets committed to the fragment manager, which runs as an async task according to the documentation

2) `onSaveInstanceState` is run to save the activity's state, which then runs `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)` - which is commented with

> Make sure all pending operations have now been executed to get
>       our state update-to-date.

3) The pending operation to replace the fragment kicks in (as it hasn't been processed yet) and crashes as the activity is already in the stopped state and I didn't account for that.

I can probably prevent my crash by checking for null and returning from the method, however it feels like creating the fragment at that point is unnecessary. Is there a way to avoid that, like telling the `FragmentManager` to drop all the pending transactions?

Comment: I don't know how to drop pending transactions. But if pending transactions are causing crash, you can execute them before activity is destroyed: `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()`. I don't know if it is a good thing to do. But might be a quick fix.

Comment: yes that's the conclusion I came to as well - thanks